# Parallel Execution not working using Appium, Cucumber with TestNG in Android Emulators

Tags: android, automation, cucumber, testng, appium-android

I have BDD framework with **TestNG** in which I tried running the Parallel execution by using **Two instances** of **Appium** with **different ports and Two Emulators**. But I am unable to run the Parallel Execution. While running the `testng.xml` file, only one emulator is getting triggered and launching application. After Launching application its getting disappear again from the emulator. There is no activity in the second emulator.

I found solutions for Web Application but I need to do it for Mobile Application. Also found that it is possible with either Cucumber or Testng. But I need to do it using Both.

Any Suggestions?